# Accept Event and Decline Event buttons not present in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning, event, calendar, sync

I have Lightning Sync configured and when I open an Event as an invitee and then I want to either accept or decline the invitation, the buttons to do this are not visible. When I switch to Classic, the buttons are there and they work. They are on the page layout, but they don't appear in Lightning. Is there any way to make them visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that's an expected behaviour and known limitation in salesforce lightning experience when you have Lightning Sync configured. From [Considerations for Using Events and Calendars in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=creating_events_lex.htm&type=5)

After you set up Lightning Sync for users, Microsoft® Exchange or Google Calendar™ sends event invitations to attendees.

> Attendees can accept or decline event invitations from their email or calendar applications **only**.

For users set up to sync both ways, attendee responses in Exchange or Google Calendar then sync to Salesforce.